# Erro ao chamar function na minha página

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou com dificuldades para chamar duas funções para validar os campos `txtnome` e `txtsobrenome`, chamando as funções `validanome()` e `validasobrenome()`.

Eu tentei chamá-las da seguinte maneira:

```
if (!validanome(cad.txtnome.value)) {
    return;  
}
if (!validasobrenome(cad.txtsobrenome.value)) {
    return;  
}
```

O código inteiro da minha página e do script [se encontra aqui](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vTGpHA-csKyjvt1UDW0bZYMEfIjwKAkJWJPo_eRrNi7xsQpIA5R_7-9C9D7wZOBViznjG5GvQ274qaz/pub).

Lá tem as duas funções, no JavaScript.

Gostaria que alguém analisasse brevemente e encontrasse o porquê de estar dando errado, no que eu estou falhando. As functions `validanome` e `validasobrenome` que citei se encontram lá no final do script, e estou tentando chamá-la na minha function `validaFormulario()`.

Obs: Eu tirei o `else` no final das function `validanome()` e `validasobrenome()`, porém não funcionou ainda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclua os `id`s `id="txtnome"` e `id="txtsobrenome"` nos campos *nome* e *sobrenome* respectivamente:

```
<input type="text" name="txtnome" id="txtnome" maxlength="40" required />
```

e

```
<input type="text" id="txtsobrenome" name="txtsobrenome" maxlength="30" required />
```

Nas funções para validar esses campos, é necessário colocar `return false` quando for inválido e `return true` quando for válido:

```
function validanome() {
   var nome = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
   var padrao = /[^a-zà-ú]/gi;
   var valida_nome = nome.match(padrao);
   if( valida_nome || !nome ){
      alert("Nome possui caracteres inválidos ou é vazio, por favor, preencha-o corretamente.");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function validasobrenome() {
   var sobrenome = document.getElementById("txtsobrenome").value;
   var padrao = /[^a-zà-ú]/gi;
   var valida_sobrenome = sobrenome.match(padrao);
   if( valida_sobrenome || !sobrenome ){
      alert("Sobrenome possui caracteres inválidos ou é vazio, por favor, preencha-o corretamente.");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

As outras funções também estão com problema, como a `muitoCurto()`, por exemplo. Deveria ser assim:

```
function muitoCurto(campo, nome, tamanho) {
   if (campo.value.length < tamanho){
      alert("O conteúdo do campo '" + nome
      + "' deve ter pelo menos " + tamanho + " caracteres."
      + " Por favor, preencha-o corretamente.");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Aí você ajusta as outras funções da mesma forma.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77753/discussion-between-dvd-and-sdkamda2323).

Answer (score 1):

Na funções que você quer chamar, já existe a chamada para o elemento que será filtrado e não possui o parametro no qual seria informado qual elemento deveria ser filtrado:

```
var nome = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
var sobrenome = document.getElementById("txtsobrenome").value;
```

Então, a chamada deve ser apenas `validanome()` e `validasobrenome()` sem parâmetros. Porém, os retornos tbm não estão de acordo com o que vc especificou nos `if()`s, devem ficar assim então as funções, sem os parâmetros:

```
function validanome() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]/gi;
    var valida_nome = nome.match(padrao);
    if( valida_nome || !nome ){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function validasobrenome(){
    var sobrenome = document.getElementById("txtsobrenome").value;
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/gi;
    var valida_sobrenome = sobrenome.match(padrao);
    if( valida_sobrenome || !sobrenome ){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
}
```

E os `if()`s para as funções sem parâmetros seriam assim:

```
if (!validanome()){
     //codigo de retorno de erro
}
if (!validasobrenome()){
     //codigo de retorno de erro
}
```

Ou com parametros:

```
function validanome(nome) {
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]/gi;
    var valida_nome = nome.match(padrao);
    if( !valida_nome || !nome ){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function validasobrenome(sobrenome){
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/gi;
    var valida_sobrenome = sobrenome.match(padrao);
    if( !valida_sobrenome || !sobrenome ){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
}
```

E os `if()`s das funções com parâmetros:

```
if (!validanome(document.getElementById("txtnome").value)){
     //codigo de retorno de erro
}
if (!validasobrenome(document.getElementById("txtsobrenome").value)){
     //codigo de retorno de erro
}
```

Comment: não entendi muito bem, é pra eu trocar as duas functions pela qual você mudou ali e depois trocar os if também?

Comment: São dois exeplos de como as funções podem rodar, nas suas funções, vc já chamava os itens pelo id dentro da função, então não precisava declarar o if como estava fazendo, deveria ser como informado no meu primeiro exemplo

Comment: oq eu tenho que fazer pra ele rodar?

Comment: trocar minhas function por essas q vc fez: function validanome(nome) {
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]/gi;
    var valida_nome = nome.match(padrao);
    if( !valida_nome || !nome ){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

function validasobrenome(sobrenome){
    var padrao = /[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú ]/gi;
    var valida_sobrenome = sobrenome.match(padrao);
    if( !valida_sobrenome || !sobrenome ){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
} e depois trocar os if?

Comment: usar um dos dois exemplos, no primeiro, vc chama a função dentro do if assim `if (!validanome())` porque a propria função vai buscar o objeto a ser verificado

Comment: sim, vc troca as funções por uma dessas que mostrei e os ifs tbm

Comment: eu usei os dois exemplos mas tá dando erro ainda, não tá chamando o erro

Comment: o dvd me ajudou com o problema que faltava, obrigado pela solução cara, vc resolveu meu problema